# Check whether an element in a data frame exists in another data frame

Tags: r, text-mining

Suppose I have the two following tables:

Table1:

```
id    word
1     apple
1     banana
2     cherry
2     donuts
3     eggplant
3     fish
```

Table2 (key_words):

```
key_words
apple
orange
cherry
peach
```

I want to check whether each element in the 'word' column of table1 exists in table2 and get the following results like:

```
id    apple   orange   cherry   peach
1       1       0        0        0
2       0       0        1        0
3       0       0        0        0
```

For example,
1 in the first row and "apple" column means id 1 does have an apple.
0 in the second row and "orange" column means id 2 doesn't have an orange.

To get such result, I wrote a for loop:

```
data=list()
data[[1]]=table1$id
l=dim(table1)[1]
for(i in 2:(length(key_words)+1)){
  exist=c()
  for(j in 1:l){
    d1=table1[which(table1$id==data[[1]][j]),]
    if(key_words[i] %in% d1$word){
      exist[j]=1
    } else {
      exist[j]=0
    }
  }
  data[[i]]=exist
}
data=as.data.frame(data)
names(data)=c("id","apple","orange","cherry","peach")
```

It does work.

However, if my table size and keywords number become much larger, for example, if I have 10,000 ids and 1,000 keywords, the for loop will run for a very long time.

Is there some faster method to shrink the running time?

Answer (score 3):

```
library(data.table)

dat <- fread("id    word
1     apple
             1     banana
             2     cherry
             2     donuts
             3     eggplant
             3     fish")


dat_key <- fread("key_words
apple
orange
cherry
peach")

dat_wide <- data.table(ID = unique(dat$id))
l <- lapply(dat_key$key_words, function(x) dat_wide[, (x) := ifelse(ID %in% dat[word == x]$id, 1, 0)][])

dat_wide

   ID apple orange cherry peach
1:  1     1      0      0     0
2:  2     0      0      1     0
3:  3     0      0      0     0
```

Comment: my reading of the Q is that it is to test that the key_words are in the main dataset ie the ther way around from your answer. (my awful dt attempt: dat[, lapply(key_words, "%in%", word ), by=id])

Comment: Thanks, I guess I read it wrong. Updated to give the correct output.

Answer (score 2):

```
data.frame(t(sapply(split(table1, table1$id), function(a)
    colSums(sapply(table2$key_words, function(x) a$word %in% x)) > 0)))
#  apple orange cherry peach
#1  TRUE  FALSE  FALSE FALSE
#2 FALSE  FALSE   TRUE FALSE
#3 FALSE  FALSE  FALSE FALSE
```

The Boolean could be changed to numeric in another step if necessary

```
temp = data.frame(t(sapply(split(table1, table1$id), function(a)
    colSums(sapply(table2$key_words, function(x) a$word %in% x)) > 0)))
data.frame(sapply(temp, as.numeric), row.names = row.names(temp))
#  apple orange cherry peach
#1     1      0      0     0
#2     0      0      1     0
#3     0      0      0     0
```

**DATA**

```
table1 = structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L), word = c("apple", 
"banana", "cherry", "donuts", "eggplant", "fish")), .Names = c("id", 
"word"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))

table2 = structure(list(key_words = c("apple", "orange", "cherry", "peach"
)), .Names = "key_words", class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```